# How to screen record a specific widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Currently, I'm using a [flutter_screen_recording](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screen_recording) to record the screen, Actually, this plugin records the full screen of the mobile. But my requirement is to record only a particular widget.

Answer (score 0):

There is a  new package called [screen_recorder](https://pub.dev/packages/screen_recorder) that can be used for exactly this.

Here's the example:

```
ScreenRecorder(
  height: 200,
  width: 200,
  background: Colors.white,
  controller: ScreenRecorderController(
    pixelRatio: 0.5,
    skipFramesBetweenCaptures: 2,
  ),
  child: // child which should be recorded
);
```

The only downsides are that it can't record platform views like the camera or a Google Maps widget and the recording must have a background color (so you can't record with a transparent background).